# Is it true that one of the medians of any triangle is the bisector of its vertical angle?

Tags: geometry

> Is it true that one of the medians (from the 3) of any triangle is the bisector of its vertical angle?
>
> If it is true, then how?

Though we know that in an equilateral triangle all the medians are the bisectors of their vertical angles.

Comment: No, it is not true.

Comment: @user - thanks.